# c++ memory leak with std::vectors

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-leaks, ram

I'm reading a `400mb` file into a c++ vector with the following code:

```
#define RAMALLOC 20000000
struct worddata {
    std::string name;
    double ussage;
};
// ...
int counter = 0;
std::string dName;
double dUssage;
std::vector<worddata> primDataBank;
primDataBank.resize(RAMALLOC);
std::ifstream fIn(PATH + "output.dat");
while (fIn >> dName >> dUssage) {
    primDataBank[counter].name = dName;
    primDataBank[counter].ussage = dUssage;
    counter++;
}
```

I have resided the vector to a size of `20,000,000` items, so as I assign to it in the loop, the ram usage shouldn't be increasing. However when I run it, the ram usage increases rapidly.

In the Visual Studio debugger heap snapshot, it shows me that the ram is being occupied by `processFrequencyData.exe!std::_Container_proxy`. The "allocation call stack" looks like so:

[image]

This appears to have its roots in the vector.

**How can I stop my ram usage from increasing?**

Thanks.

**Update:**

My ram usage still increases rapidly when I comment out the lines of code in the while loop that assign values

```
while (fIn >> dName >> dUssage) {
    //primDataBank[counter].name = dName;
    //primDataBank[counter].ussage = dUssage;
    counter++;
}
```

However ram usage doesn't increase when I also comment out the vector code:

```
//std::vector<worddata> primDataBank;
//primDataBank.resize(RAMALLOC);
```

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve]?

Comment: can you issue a pause in your program just after having resized the vector? When you hit the pause, you should see memory not been allocated anymore.

Comment: *I have resided the vector to a size of 20,000,000 items, so as I assign to it in the loop, the ram usage shouldn't be increasing.* Uh ... yes it should. Your vector initially contains *empty strings* which you fill up while doing the loop, those take memory too.

Comment: @Borgleader Don't strings have a fixed memory size?

Comment: @FelisPhasma No, std::string works very much like std::vector actually.

Comment: @FelisPhasma: Do you think that *"my"* and *"encyclopedia"* have the same size? Besides, developers worrying about **RAM** usage have failed to understand (virtual) memory management, as implemented in virtually any desktop OS.

Comment: Thanks @IInspectable and Borgleader for the help

Comment: Just an aside, but it looks like (from the code you provided) a more suitable data structure would be a `std::map<std::string, double>` for your scenario.

Comment: Do you have the 8GB of RAM this vector will take, even if all strings are empty or small enough for SSO?

Comment: Btw which version of VC are you using?

Comment: @Surt VC 2015 update 3

Comment: @BaummitAugen I have 16 gigs of ram on my machine. Windows won't let me use more than 2gb though

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit version of Windows? If so, why did you waste those 12GB of RAM? If you aren't running a 32-bit version of Windows, why do you assume, that Windows would only let you use 2GB?

Comment: @IInspectable I am using 64-bit. I have plenty of ram available, however windows locks the program so it can't use too much ram. As soon as it uses more than 2gb, windows forces the program to `abort();`.

Comment: There is nothing built into Windows that would do what you describe. Windows (the OS) doesn't even know about `abort()` (a CRT function). What's more likely is, that your allocations fail once you have depleted your share of the virtual address space, and the unhandled exception shuts down the process in a controlled fashion. If you need more than 2GB, either use [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) (granting you 4GB), or build a 64-bit application (why aren't you anyway?).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I'll use that.

Comment: @IInspectable An for clarification, windows forces the program to quit. Not by calling `abort()`, however the debug error says `abort()` has been called.

Comment: *"windows forces the program to quit"* - That's not what's happening. It's the **program** that decides to terminate. The OS has no way to call `abort()` on a program, or force a program to call `abort()`. It's either the result of an unhandled C++ exception, that makes the program eventually call `abort()`, or an unhandled SEH exception (probably an access violation as a result of failure to allocate memory). Regardless of what it is, it is the program that decides to terminate, not the OS.

Comment: @IInspectable ok. I'll try /LARGEADDRESSAWARE.

Comment: Uhm... that's a kludge, and you need to know, what you are doing. Can you guarantee, that your code is prepared to deal with 32-bit pointers (vs. 31-bit)? If you cannot, don't just blindly enable a linker flag that might break your program. It's **way** easier to just compile a 64-bit application. And it's way less problematic. And it gives you **way** [more address space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778.aspx) than a meager 4 GB (8 TB or 128 TB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector your creating uses approximately

20000000 * 32 bytes = 640 000 000 ie 640 MB // who said 640K would be enough?

The size of worddata comes from std::string is around 24 bytes + 8 for the double.

Then you start reading strings, if they are sufficiently small the string will maybe use small-string-optimization, that is using the internal data and capacity for storing the chars.
But if they are larger than ~12(???) chars the string allocates an extra array to keep the chars.

The updates requires more investigation.

Comment: The longest string I need is 11 characters long. It would be very nice to only use 640kb of memory, as my program is currently trying to use more than 2gb...

Comment: @FelisPhasma, Well with 400 MB text you would need a substantiel amount of memory with your current structure. You could try something else for the text, for example tries.

Answer (score 1):

Your memory use increases because you are creating and storing all those strings you read from the file.

A string is not a fixed size object so the only way you can pre-allocate space for strings is to use a custom allocator.

You should prefer using **reserve** and **emplace_back** rather than **resize** and setting fields as this will avoid allocating 0 length strings you don't need.

I find your update hard to believe.